# Negative numbers in PDF content stream text object

Tags: pdf

What is the meaning of the negative numbers that are interspersed between strings in a PDF text object. For example, in

```
/F1 1 Tf
4.2622 0 TD
[(has)-333.9(not)-334.7(been)-333.9(elucidated)-10.7(.)]TJ
```

I get everything going on except the `-333.9`, `-334.7`, `-10.7`.

My questions are:

- What are they called?
- Where are they discussed in the PDF reference?
- They don't seem to be transforms. Do they modify info the font dictionary?

Answer (score 5):

The lines of PDF source code you quote

```
/F1 1 Tf 
4.2622 0 TD 
[(has)-333.9(not)-334.7(been)-333.9(elucidated)-10.7(.)]TJ
```

may be decoded like this:

- **`/F1`**:
  This sets the current font to one named `/F1`. (This is only a short name -- what real font that is, is defined elsewhere in the PDF.)
- **`1 Tf`**:
  This selects the text font and sets its size to `1` (in text space units), because `Tf` is the equivalent to the `selectfont` operator in PostScript.
- **`4.2622 0 TD`**:
  This moves the text position to `4.2622 0` and also sets the text leading. `TD` has no direct equivalent in PostScript.
- **`[....]TJ`**:
  This defines how a string is composed. The `TJ` is a similar operator as `show` is for PostScript. The difference is that `TJ` allows for individual glyph positioning. The `[....]` defines an array of individual, smaller strings.
- **`(has)`, `(not)`, `(been)`, `(elucidated)` and `(.)`**:
  These are individual parts of the complete text placed within the `[....]` array.
- **`-333.9`, `-334.7`, `-333.9` and `-10.7`**:
  These numbers adjust the respective text position by that amount. Numbers are expressed in *thousandths* of a unit of text space. According to **the official PDF spec**, this *"amount shall be **subtracted** from the current horizontal or vertical coordinate"*. A positive number therefor moves the next string to the *left* when writing horizontally. A negative number moves it to the right.

**So in effect, in this example PDF code, the negative numbers determine the respective word distances.**

---

### References

1. To get an overview of PDF operators (and their mapping to matching PostScript operator names, if there is one), have a look at *page 643* of the following document:

   - **[PDF32000_2008, PDF-1.7 Specification (Annex A: Operator Summary)](http://acroeng.adobe.com/PDFReference/ISO32000/PDF32000-Adobe.pdf#page=651)**
2. For the official explanation about the `TJ` operator and the preceeding array, see *table 109 on page 250* of the same document:

   - **[PDF32000_2008, PDF-1.7 Specification (Text-Showing Operators)](http://acroeng.adobe.com/PDFReference/ISO32000/PDF32000-Adobe.pdf#page=258)**