# How to comma separate words when using Pypdf2 library

Tags: python, data-science, text-analysis, pypdf

I'm converting pdf to text convertion using PyPDF2 and during this code some words are mixing, the code is shown below :-

```
filename = 'CS1.pdf'      
pdfFileObj = open(filename,'rb')       
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)      
num_pages = pdfReader.numPages  
count = 0      
text = ""    

while count < num_pages:       
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(count)  
    count +=1  
    print(pageObj)  
    text += pageObj.extractText()
if text != "":  
   text = text  
else:  
   text = textract.process('/home/ayush/Ayush/1june/pdf_to_text/CS1.pdf', method='tesseract', language='eng')
print(text)
```

output:-

Topursuegraduatestudiesincomputerscienceandengineering

how can i expect

To,pursue,graduate,studies,in,computer,science,and,engineering

Comment: What is `textract`? It is missing in your example. The output text in your example, was it created by `pageObj.extractText()` or `textract`?

Comment: Textract is the library which is besically used in textual analysis and visualization. pageObj.extractText() is the function which defined in PyPDF2 library this function generate text.

Comment: @AayushSharma you just want commas between words ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add

```
text += pageObj.extractText()
print(pageObj.extractText())
```

How does the text look at that stage before the concatenation?

I might have found the reason. Download [iText RUPS](https://github.com/itext/rups/releases/tag/5.5.9) to inspect the pdf. This tool shows how the content is rendered and placed on the page.

Navigate to `Stream`

[image]

In the lower right corner you can read

[image]

I am not familiar with the PDF spec, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28203655/7919597) answer states

> These numbers adjust the respective text position by that amount.
>   Numbers are expressed in thousandths of a unit of text space.
>   According to the official PDF spec, this "amount shall be subtracted
>   from the current horizontal or vertical coordinate". A positive number
>   therefor moves the next string to the left when writing horizontally.
>   A negative number moves it to the right.

My suspicion is that `PyPDF2` does not interpret a number as space. This is probably not that easy as you have to know how many pixels equal a space character.

I had a quick look in another pdfs and the text with spaces instead of numbers in between is read correctly. Please try that.

If this is the problem your next move could be to iterate the elements as shown in iText RUPS directly. It is a bit cumbersome but possible. You can find examples for `PyPDF2`.

Comment: Same output before the concatenation.

Comment: String without spaces.

Comment: Could you upload an example pdf somewhere?